# Elasticsearch query with multiple attributs and values

Tags: php, elasticsearch, drupal

I try to construct, in php, an query with different attribut:
this following code work :

```
$searchParams = [
    'body' => [
        "from"=> 0,
        "size"=> 30000,
        'query' => [
            'filtered'=> [
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            'terms' => [
                                'field_support' => [105,106,1896,1897]
                            ]
                        ]

                     ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

But when i add "term" it's not working:

```
$searchParams = [
    'body' => [
        "from"=> 0,
        "size"=> 30000,
        'query' => [
            'filtered'=> [
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            'terms' => [
                                'field_support' => [105,106,1896,1897]
                            ],
                            'term' => [
                                'title' => ["le jeu de la dame"]
                            ]
                        ]

                     ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I don't understand why it's doesn't works.
Can somebody help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround your `terms` and `term` query with another associative array, like this:

```
$searchParams = [
    'body' => [
        "from"=> 0,
        "size"=> 30000,
        'query' => [
            'filtered'=> [
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                           [
                            'terms' => [
                                'field_support' => [105,106,1896,1897]
                            ]
                           ],
                           [
                            'term' => [
                                'title' => ["le jeu de la dame"]
                            ]
                           ]
                        ]

                     ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

**UPDATE**

Variant with `match`

```
$searchParams = [
    'body' => [
        "from"=> 0,
        "size"=> 30000,
        'query' => [
            'filtered'=> [
                'query' => [
                    'match' => [
                        'title' => ["le jeu de la dame"]
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    'terms' => [
                        'field_support' => [105,106,1896,1897]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks, i have not error. But i have no result : [total] = 0. I don't understund why ? ...

Comment: At first glance, probably the second `term` query should be a `match` instead.

Comment: Yes ! I delete 'term', and i add                                                                     'query' => [
                'match'=> [
                    'title' => "le jeu de la dame"
                ],                                                                                                                    but i have an error : Parse Failure, nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT \"filtered\"];